# Use method from another Class in Object from ArrayList

Tags: java

```
    ListIterator litr = PuntenLijst.listIterator();

    while(litr.hasNext()){
       Object Punt = litr.next();
       Punt.print();
    }
```

PuntenLijst is an ArrayList that contains object instances from another Class.

Now I have made a method print() that prints out something from that object (of the other class).

With this loop I try to loop through the ArrayList, and then use the print() method from the other class, but it doesn't not seem to be working.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Object Punt = litr.next();
   Punt.print();
```

You need to cast your `Punt` to appropriate class, of which you have the ArrayList.

Of course `print()` is not a method of `Object` class

**Suppose you have ArrayList like this: -**

```
ArrayList<YourClass> PuntenLijst
```

Change your invocation to: -

```
Object Punt = litr.next();
((YourClass)Punt).print();
```

Or: -

```
   YourClass Punt = litr.next();
   Punt.print();
```

Comment: If the declaration is `ArrayList<YourClass>` no cast is needed. just do `YourClass Punt = litr.next();`

Comment: @ColinD Oh yeah. I myself forgot that I assumed ArrayList that way.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the object you get as response for `litr.next()` to corresponding type and call method on that type.

Example:

```
     Punt puntObj =(Punt) litr.next();
       puntObj.print();
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast `Punt` to the type that contains the `Print()` method.

```
while(litr.hasNext()){
       TYPE_THAT_HAS_PRINT Punt = (TYPE_THAT_HAS_PRINT) litr.next();
       Punt.print();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use for:each loop? The casting is taken care by the JVM provided you've defined PuntenLijst with the correct Type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `Object` type to the type your actual object is.

Comment: maybe. In the code snip provided, `Punt` is just a variable name. The poster has not provided what types of objects are stored in his list.